# PHP: literal \n rather than new line

Tags: php

I have a php var which, when echoed, writes a JS function into the source of a page. The function loops through a CSV and so it has the following line within it:

```
$str="var lines = data.split('\n');";
```

At the present time, when echoed, I get this 'correct' JS written into the source:

```
var lines = data.split('
');
```

Instead, I want to echo the literal string `\n` into the source of the page.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Escape the slash.

```
"\\n"
```

So that it is treated as a slash instead of an escape character.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$str="var lines = data.split('\\n');";
```

Comment: some explanation would be nice, nobody learns from copy&paste ;)

Answer (score -1):

you can escape `\` like this: `\\`.

But I would put the whole JS functionality into a .js file, include that from the generated HTML, and call the specific function when needed. And generate a minimalistic js code, like `var config = {....}` if I have to communicate some page related information.

You almost never need dynamically generated JS code. It's a lot harder to read and you're wasting CPU and network bandwidth...

Answer (score -1):

Either the solutions in the earlier answers, or invert the quotes by using single quotes as the PHP string delimiter:

```
$str='var lines = data.split("\n");';
```

Or escape the inner quotes, if you want to keep single quotes for javascript as well when using single quotes as the PHP string delimiter.

```
$str='var lines = data.split(\'\n\');';
```

See the [docs on quoted strings in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax) as well about how single quoted strings and double quoted strings behave differently.